# angular make ng-options value selected based on external input like cookie

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a select with `ng-options` from an object. Nothing wrong with it, functions fine.

Now, on `ng-change`, I'm writing the value into a cookie (using `cookies`).

When the page refreshes, I check if value is available in the `cookies`, if so, set the model value for this `dropdown` to the cookie value.

Works fine as in I get the `vm.code` value from cookie as last selected before refresh.

But I need the dropdown to have the appropriate option selected as its `ng-model` is code. ---> Not happening.

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/daloyQMBrtzZcLx4mfTO?p=preview)

To see the cookie values, change the option in dropdown, then Stop and Run the plunker again.

Ideas/suggestions welcome. In the bog here.

Comment: can you add your code ?

Answer (score 0):

#### Screenshot from developer tool:

[image]

I look through your plunk and realized when setValue method triggered $event object state always stays undefined. I am not sure of the solution but it might be a case which you missed out.

Comment: $event would show as undefined as it is not accessible in that way. In the dev tools, at this point, if you hover on 'event', it will show you the event object.